# Coffee machine queue

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

A coffee vending machine which only sells 0.5 € coffee cups, accepts only 1 and 0.5 € coins. At a given moment when it is empty of coins, there are $m+n$ people queuing to buy their coffee cups. $m$ of them carry a 1 € coin, while $n$ of them have a 0.5 € one. How many queues are possible if their ordering is forced to always give change to people paying with a 1 € coin?

Comment: Is this sequence not generalised Catalan numbers?

Comment: Lets say you are going through queue - at any given time, you should have n>=m… but "how many queues"?

Comment: I would say it is exactly same problem as we had in school: "One step forward/backward with same probability, if you standing in front of abyss - what is the probability of surviving after X moves?" or something like that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's call someone a Halfer if they have a €0.50 coin and a Wholer if they have a €1.00 coin. The problem is essentially to find the number of possible queues such that

> for any $k$, among the first $k$ people in the queue there are at least as many Halfers as Wholers,

since the machine takes a €0.50 coin from every Halfer and needs to give one to every Wholer.

---

Let $H$ denote a Halfer and $W$ denote a Wholer. We want to find the number of sequences of $H$'s and $W$'s such that

> no initial segment of the sequence contains more $W$ 's than $H$ 's.

This is precisely the number of [**Dyck words**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dyck_word) of length $m+n$. For $m=n$, the answer is therefore

> the $n$th [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics) $C_n$.

In general, we seek the formula for the number of lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,m)$ which stay below the line $y=x$. According to Ira Gessel's *Introduction to Lattice Path Enumeration*, as cited in [this Math Overflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/1971/61630), the formula for this is

> $\frac{n-m}{m+n}\binom{m+n}{m}=\frac{(m-n)(m+n-1)!}{m!n!}$.

If we count two 'queues' as being different if they have the $m$ Wholers (or the $n$ Halfers) in the same positions but in a different order, then our final answer is

> $(m-n)(m+n-1)!$.

Comment: I would say probability of death = m/n for large numbers . Don't know how to compute it for small numbers.